# Null values when retrieving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I have an attendance app that contains multiple users, I am trying to retrieve and display some of the user details to a list name/surname/empId. When my code is executed it retrieves and shows the first name but not the other 2 values. When debugged the values show as NULL and i cant not see what I have missed. hopefully some fresh eyes can help

any help really appreciated - code below with images

```
[//Activity code to get data

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseOut.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);                   
                userList.add(user);

            }
            zz_List_Users userListAdapter = new zz_List_Users(updateEmployeeDetailsActivity.this, userList);
            listViewUsers.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}][1]
```

//User list code of data i want to retrieved and add to the list

```
public class zz_List_Users extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private Activity context;
    List<User> userList;

    public zz_List_Users(Activity context, List<User> userList) {
        super(context, R.layout.zz_list_user, userList);
        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zz_list_user, null, true);

        TextView textViewNameU = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameU);
        TextView textViewSurname = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewSurnameU);
        TextView textViewEmpId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmpIdU);

        User user = userList.get(position);

        textViewSurname.setText(user.getSurname());
        textViewEmpId.setText(user.getEmpId());
        textViewNameU.setText(user.getName());


        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

//User Class

```
public class User {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String empId;
    private String password;
    private String address;
    private String postCode;
    private String userEmail;
    public boolean adminUser;


    public User(){

    }

    public User(String userId, String name, String surname, String empId, String password, String address, String postCode, String userEmail, boolean adminUser) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.empId = empId;
        this.password = password;
        this.address =  address;
        this.postCode =  postCode;
        this.userEmail =  userEmail;
        this.adminUser = adminUser;


    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getEmpId() { return empId; }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getAddress() { return address;    }

    public String getPostCode() {return postCode;    }

    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;    }

    public boolean getAdminUser() {return adminUser;    }
}
```

Any help really appreciated

```
//Firebase JSON

{
  "users" : {
    "1mXbSGCzGmbCp7lLXjxjX2kihHI3" : {
      "address" : "31 moyola drive shantallow",
      "adminUser" : true,
      "employeeId" : "902488",
      "firstName" : "Sarah",
      "password" : "solskjaer",
      "postCode" : "bt48 0GE",
      "surname" : "Breslin",
      "userEmail" : "sarahbreslin81@hotmail.com",
      "userId" : "1mXbSGCzGmbCp7lLXjxjX2kihHI3"
    },
    "O0MYu0YmENgodYSHU0BkMSFQCFj2" : {
      "address" : "123 Elaghmore Park",
      "adminUser" : true,
      "employeeId" : "902499",
      "firstName" : "Seamus",
      "password" : "solskjaer",
      "postCode" : "BT48 8DY",
      "surname" : "Ferry",
      "userEmail" : "seamyferry@hotmail.co.uk",
      "userId" : "O0MYu0YmENgodYSHU0BkMSFQCFj2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your code looks fine.did the list<User> retrieved from firebase contains all users and these users have all their fields with no Null?

Comment: yeah get everything except the first name and employee id, I added an image there of the list result. only 2 users in it at the minute.

Comment: there is no problem with the list view. add your firebase JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your fields must have the same name as it is in the firebase response.

so in `User` class change `name` to `firstName` as in your response. also `empId` to `employeeId`.

the same for other fields.

so use this [**tool**](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate your **POJO** to avoid this kind of problems.

there is a helpful [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo) in Android studio too.

Comment: I only changed those because because i thought i did have them the same but still wasn't working but i must have had a capital letter or something wrong in the User class. Absolute idiot, thanks for your help Bishoy, gentleman

Answer (score -1):

Your fields in the user class must be the same as in Firebase.firstName and employeeId are the fields in ur json response.But in the users class you gave name and empid.So replace them with firstName and employeeId.The fields in the user class must have the same names as in firebase